# Laravel returns 404 on existing controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have just started using laravel and I love it, however I have encountered an issue,

Routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'SongsController@index'); => this works perfectly
Route::get('/index', 'SongsController@index'); => this fails and returns 404
Route::get('index', 'SongsController@index'); => this also returns 404
```

Comment: It  was from mod_rewrite, everything is back to normal again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to note here:

As a rule of thumb, most generic matches should appear at the bottom as not to be triggered prior to more specific routes:

```
Route::get('/index', 'SongsController@index');
Route::get('/', 'SongsController@index');
```

Next, make sure that you -can- access the route by appending `index.php` prior to the route.

```
http://my.site.tld/index.php/index
```

If that resolves but it doesn't without the index.php, do two things:

- make sure mod_headers is enabled.

  - sudo a2enmod headers - ubuntu
  - modify httpd.conf and check for mod_headers.so (ensure not commented out) - RHEL/CentOS
- make sure that "AllowOverride All" has been configured in your `<Directory>` block within your virtualhost for "my.site.tld"

This should ensure that the route will resolve.